# "Cut" records from one table into another in one oracle sql statement

Tags: oracle

I have a very big table T1 and i would like to copy every 15000 records to T2. 
After that I want to delete these same records.
I want a fast and efficient way.
I tried this but it wouldn't work :

```
merge into T2 T 
using (select col1,col2 from T1 where rownum<15000) m 
on (1=1) 
when matched then 
insert values (m.col1,m.col2)
delete where 1=1;
```

It's giving me a syntax error. Any ideas??
Please help.
Thanks

Comment: The `delete` part of a `merge` statement will delete rows in the **target** table - in your case `T2`. It will not delete rows from the "source" table. There is no way you can do that with a single statement in Oracle. You **will** need two statements.

Comment: Why do you need a single statement?You can do it in a single transaction.

Answer (score -2):

Try (works on sql server)

```
INSERT T2 (
      col1,col2
) SELECT col1,col2
      FROM    (
           DELETE T1
           OUTPUT
                   DELETED.col1,
                   DELETED.col2
           WHERE rownum<15000
      ) AS RowsToMove;
```